# how mysql update self table work

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

I have a table in MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tem(a INT,b INT);
```

With below data:

```
INSERT INTO test.tem VALUES(1,2),(1,1),(1,NULL),(2,3);
```

Now the data should be:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

I want to update column b to the min(b) group by column a.

So the SQL should be:

```
UPDATE test.tem o
SET o.b = (SELECT
             MIN(b)
           FROM test.tem i
           WHERE i.a = o.a)
```

But MYSQL **Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause**

So I think below SQL can solve my question with good performance:

```
UPDATE test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
SET t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.b IS NULL
     OR t1.b > t2.b;
```

But the result is:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

Actually the result I need is :

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

Question 1: Why MYSQL work out the incorrect result with the SQL? What the correct SQL with good efficient should  be?
Question 2: What the SQL should be if I only want to update b with NULL value(only update the third record)?

About question 2, I have tried to use the incorrect SQL below:

```
UPDATE test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
    AND t1.b IS NULL
SET t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.b IS NULL
     OR t1.b > t2.b;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an unique column to identifies your rows. So your`JOIN` will probably update more rows as you think.

---

You probably want something like that instead:

```
UPDATE tem AS t1 JOIN (SELECT a, MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a) AS t2
USING (a)
SET t1.b = t2.m;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6a04/1

---

If you only want to update the rows having `NULL` in column *b*, this is only a matter of `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE tem(a INT,b INT);    
INSERT INTO tem VALUES(1,2),(1,1),(1,NULL),(2,3);

UPDATE tem AS t1 JOIN (SELECT a, MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a) AS t2
USING (a)
SET t1.b = t2.m
WHERE t1.b IS NULL;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ffb/1

Comment: It takes about 5 minutes to update in one table with 4.5 million records using your SQL. Can you help me find out the fault of my SQL?

Comment: @bluearrow As this is a different topic, you should ask an other question, providing your table structure (incl. your index), the request and its [query plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/execution-plan-information.html).

Comment: Look forward your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117717/mysql-join-update-internal-steps

Answer (score 1):

[Write it as a `JOIN` instead](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/762ec/1):

```
UPDATE tem
JOIN ( SELECT a, MIN(b) AS min_b FROM tem GROUP BY a ) AS mins USING (a)
SET tem.b = mins.min_b ;
```

Comment: That's a good method. But I think the mins table has no index. Can you help me find out the fault of my SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary table to do this:

```
create temporary table tem2 (a INT, b INT);

insert into tem2 
  select a, min(b) from tem group by a;

update tem
  inner join tem2 on tem.a = tem2.a
  set tem.b = tem2.b;

drop table tem2;
```

I think that should work. The 'drop table' is not strictly necessary since tem2 will be dropped anyway when the connection is closed, although it's good form.