# MYSQL join update internal steps

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Use the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tem(a INT,b INT,INDEX (a),INDEX (b));
INSERT INTO test.tem VALUES(1,2),(1,1),(1,NULL),(2,3);
```

Now the data should be:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

I want to update column b to the min(b) group by column a.
I have known one correct SQL is:

```
UPDATE tem AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT a,MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a) AS t2
    USING (a)
SET t1.b = t2.m;
```

Producing the correct result is:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

However, it takes about 5 minutes to update in one table with 4.5 million records using this SQL query.

So, I have one SQL of myself:

```
UPDATE test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
SET t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.b > t2.b
     OR t1.b IS NULL;
```

But it gets the incorrect result:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

I think the reason is about how MYSQL work when update. Can anyone tell me *how* the incorrect result come out? If someone could fix *my* SQL that would help too.

Comment: I've heavily edited your question according to the comments you left on http://stackoverflow.com/a/18081509/2363712. Please review those changes and fix the possible typos, misunderstandings and other errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "query not updating correctly the rows":

You want to update column `b` to the *minimum* of `b` for all rows having the same `a`

You proposed to use the following `JOIN` to do that:

```
UPDATE test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
SET t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.b > t2.b
     OR t1.b IS NULL;
```

Contrary to what you may think, that `JOIN` will not perform a 1-1 `JOIN`. It is in fact a many-to-many `JOIN` since [as I said yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081509/2363712) you don't use primary key (nor non-null unique key) in your join clause.

In fact, rewriting that query as as `SELECT` will probably help you to understand the problem:

```
SELECT t1.a as t1a, t1.b as t1b, t2.a as t2a,t2.b as t2b FROM tem t1 JOIN tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE t1.b > t2.b
     OR t1.b IS NULL;

+------+---------+------+--------+
| T1A  |  T1B    | T2A  |  T2B   |
+------+---------+------+--------+
|   1  | (null)  |   1  | 2      |
|   1  | 2       |   1  | 1      |
|   1  | (null)  |   1  | 1      |
|   1  | (null)  |   1  | (null) |
+------+---------+------+--------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/856a7/8

As you will see now, the row `(1, null)` match `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)` and `(1, null)`. Depending the (non-deterministic) order of execution of the query, this might assign any of the three possible values for `b` ('m not sure about that, but *maybe* even updating it *several* times). To some extend, you have been lucky to find the "wrong" result while testing!

I hope this explain a little bit more why your query does not produce the expected result. Since multi-table [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statements don't allow `ORDER BY` nor `GROUP BY` clauses, as of myself, to find the "good" result, I don't see many other options than finding the minimum *first* through a sub-query...

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much for your patience. I have thought the (1 NULL) records would be updated several times, but I did't think about MYSQL query the data first and then update records by the query data. I what to find a better way to update in such situation and until now "join with sub-query" is the best.

Answer (score 2):

The one *main* thing you could do to increase the execution speed of your query is to use proper index to optimize the `WHERE`/`USING` clauses.

```
UPDATE tem AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT a,MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a) AS t2
    USING (a)
SET t1.b = t2.m;
```

This requests has a `USING(a)` clause. The fastest MySQL would be able to match column `a` the fastest query will run. So you will have to add an index on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE tem ADD INDEX (a);
```

As a matter of fact, since the sub-query is using both `GROUB BY(a)` and `MIN(b)`, an index on `(a,b)` would most probably perform even better:

```
ALTER TABLE tem ADD INDEX (a,b);
```

In order to be sure of that, you might have to examine the query plan (see `EXPLAIN`  below).

---

The second query is:

```
UPDATE test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
    ON t1.a = t2.a
SET t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.b > t2.b
     OR t1.b IS NULL;
```

I *don't* answer here to "what's wrong with my query". But from a pure performance perspective, since this query use the column `b` in the `WHERE` clause, you would optimize its execution you will have at least to add an index on `b`.

```
ALTER TABLE tem ADD INDEX (b);
```

---

As a hint, when you have a *slow* `SELECT` query, you might use [`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to examine the *query plan* in order to check if/how MySQL use the indexes.

Rewriting here you two queries as `SELECT` statements, that would give:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t1.b = t2.b
  FROM tem AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT a,MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a) AS t2
  USING (a);

EXPLAIN SELECT t1.b = t2.b
  FROM test.tem t1
  JOIN test.tem t2
  ON t1.a = t2.a
  WHERE t1.b > t2.b
     OR t1.b IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have added the index at the beginning. The "5 minutes 4.5 million records" table also has similar index(the table struct is different). I think MYSQL will generate one temporary table for **SELECT a,MIN(b) AS m FROM tem GROUP BY a** and this table has no index. That's where it waste some time. The most import thing of this topic is to find why my SQL comes incorrect result :)

Comment: +1 for the `(a,b)` index. This is needed for both versions of the query (the correct working one and the not working.)

Comment: @ypercube Perfectly right: I was so focused on the `WHERE` clause that I didn't see the `ON` join clause O_o (BTW, thank you for editing my answer!)

Comment: @bluearrow How many rows are returned by the sub-query `SELECT a, MIN(b) ...` ?